# Why am I seeing a crash when displaying this table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am designing a simple navigation based application for EmployeeContactDirectory. I am displaying the list of Employee. For showing the list of employee, I am using the restfull webservice. I am getting proper response as I want. I have a utility class for Employee Data, class is EmployeeData.h and Employee.m (contains employeeId , employeeFirstName, employeeLastName). My code for parsing

```
// Code for parsing the response and getting desired field into the dictionary object and add the dictionaries into the array.     
    -(void)finishedReceivingData:(NSData *)data {   
        NSData *dataRes = [[restConnection stringData] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        ////////////////Parsing with XPathQuery Start//////////////////////
        if (dataRes != NULL) {
        employeeData = [[EmployeeData alloc] init];
        NSString *xPathQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/*",employeeData.employeeID];
        NSArray *arrayWithObjectList = PerformXMLXPathQuery(dataRes, xPathQuery);
        for(NSDictionary *childOfObjectList in arrayWithObjectList){
        NSArray *arrayOfDataValueObj = (NSArray *)[childOfObjectList objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"];
       for(NSDictionary *childObjListDict in arrayOfDataValueObj){
       NSArray *childObjListDataValue = (NSArray *)[childObjListDict objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"];
       for(NSDictionary *childDict in childObjListDataValue){
    if([[childDict objectForKey:@"nodeName"] isEqualToString:@"FName" ])
       {
       employeeData.employeeFirstName = [childDict objectForKey:@"nodeContent"];
       }
       if([[childDict objectForKey:@"nodeName"] isEqualToString:@"EmpID"])
       {
       employeeData.employeeID = [childDict objectForKey:@"nodeContent"];
       }
       }
       //employeeFirstNameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:employeeData, nil];
       employeeIDArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:employeeData, nil];
       dictionaryEmployeeFirstName = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:employeeData.employeeFirstName forKey:@"employeeData"];
       dictionaryEmployeeID = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:employeeData.employeeID forKey:@"employeeData"];
       tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dictionaryEmployeeFirstName, dictionaryEmployeeID, nil];
       NSLog(@"size of temp %d",[tempArray count]);
       }
       }
      //[employeeData release];
      //employeeData = nil;
      }
      [self.tableviewEmloyeeList reloadData];
    //////////////////////////////Parsing with XPathQuery end//////////
    } 


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        } 
        // Configure the cell..
       NSDictionary *dictionaryEmployee = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       NSArray *firstNameArray = [dictionaryEmployee objectForKey:@"employeeData"];
       NSString *cellValue = [firstNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       NSLog(@"cellValue %@",cellValue);
       cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

       return cell;
    }
```

I am getting the message (Exc_bad_Access) when this line of code comes into the execution flow:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryEmployee = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

The EXC_Bad_Access is at the mail.m file at line nt retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

So, Please tell me how can I set the data into the tableview when I am using NSDictionary. When, user clicks on the row of the tableview it will return the id of the selected employee.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line

```
tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dictionaryEmployeeFirstName, dictionaryEmployeeID, nil];
```

try the following,

```
if( tempArray )
{
   [tempArray release];
   tempArray = nil;
}

tempArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dictionaryEmployeeFirstName, dictionaryEmployeeID, nil] retain];
```

Since it is autoreleased, it might have been out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a tableView delegate method called

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

here you will get the section & row clicked in the table